# Differentiability of $f(x,y) = | |x| - |y| | - |x| - |y|$ at $(0,0) \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have an exercise in a multivariable calculus book that asks me to find out whether
$f(x,y) = | |x| - |y| | - |x| - |y|$ is differentiable at $(0,0) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$. I have tried to do this without success.
Can someone help provide a hint or an answer for this problem ? I have found that the partial
derivatives $f_{x}(0,0)$ and $f_{y}(0,0)$ exist. I have also found that the directional derivatives (denoted $\boldsymbol{D_{u}}f(0,0)$) at $(0,0)$ do not exist exist. Note here
$\boldsymbol{u} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is such that $\lVert u \rVert = 1$.

Comment: Try sketching a graph of this surface. If some directional derivatives don't exist then ...

Comment: Usually, the definition of differentiable is this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition). Using that definition, one can show that if a function is differentiable then its directional derivatives must exist.

Comment: One candidate for a differential is a $0$ functional so you can show $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{||x|-|y||-|x|-|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ doesn't exist. For example, this limit depends on $a$: $$\frac{||x|-|ax||-|x|-|ax|}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2x^2}}=\frac{|1-|a||\cdot|x|-(1+|a|)|x|}{\sqrt{1+a^2}|x|}=\frac{|1-|a||+1+|a|}{1+a^2}$$ or you could done something as in the accepted answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2088912/942722).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and consider the map $g\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R^2$ defined by $g(x)=(x,x)$, which is differentiable. So, if $f$ was differentiable at $(0,0)$, then $f\circ g$ would be differentiable at $0$. But$$(\forall x\in\Bbb R):f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=-2|x|.$$